# Calendar allways returns the same date

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the current day of the week and week of the year like this:
Declaring my variable like this:

```
Calendar calWeek;
Calendar calDay;
```

Setting the values like this:

```
calWeek = Calendar.getInstance();
calWeek.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calWeek.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Calendar.MONDAY);

calDay = Calendar.getInstance();
calDay.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

int currentWeek = calWeek.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int dayInWeek = calDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

`currentWeek` returns 2 and `dayInWeek` returns 2. The current week is 1 and it's Wednesday. (3rd day of the week)

Even if i change the date on my device, the output is the same, `currentWeek` returns 2 and `dayInWeek` returns 2.

Why does it always return the same date?

Best regards,
Dridia

Comment: They're both returning `2` because you're setting both to `Calendar.MONDAY`, which has a value of `2`. The `Calendar.getInstance()` method returns a `Calendar` object with the current date already set, so just remove both `set()` calls.

Comment: what do you expect `calWeek.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Calendar.MONDAY);` to do?

Comment: @njzk2 I have no idea... It's completely useless for this kind of purpose. Removing both `set()` calls fixed the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Mike M's comment: you set both values to `Calendar.MONDAY` which is equals to `2`.

`Calendar.getInstance()` returns an instance with the current date but if you call `calendarInstance.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)` you still get 2 because according to the docs:

> When setting or getting the WEEK_OF_MONTH or WEEK_OF_YEAR fields, Calendar must determine the first week of the month or year as a reference point. **The first week of a month or year is defined as the earliest seven day period beginning on getFirstDayOfWeek() and containing at least  [getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()) days of that month or year**....

I just tried it and `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()`returns `1` by default. So you should set this to `7` days. So the first Week will begin on Monday as you expect.

One instance of Calendar is sufficient and your code should look like this:

```
Calendar calendarInstance = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarInstance.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calendarInstance.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(7);
int currentWeek = calendarInstance.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int dayInWeek = calendarInstance.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
System.out.println("week = " + currentWeek);
System.out.println("day of week = " + dayInWeek);
```

prints:

```
week = 1
day of week = 4
```

P.S. 4 means Wednesday